# Insert HTML <base> into iframe

Tags: php, javascript-objects

I'm attempting to insert the `base` HTML tag into an iframe that loads a remote URL.

```
<iframe name="frame" id="frame" src="proxy.php" width="550" height="150"></iframe>
```

The contents of Proxy.php is below

```
$url = 'https://theurl.com/buyflow/buyflow-localization.html'; 
$probe = file_get_contents($url);
echo $probe;
```

The frame loads all absolute links correctly, but when attempting to load a relative link it refers to my localhost (local web server) @ 127.0.0.1

Comment: Can you show how and where you insert the `base` tag? It's not clear whether you do this using a script or just wrote it to the file. It is also not clear where those files are located and what is the result you expect.

Comment: @YakovL I would like the <base href="https://theurl.com"> to be nested in the <head> tag. I need this done through proxy.php, so that the iframe will look on the remote server for resources (images, scripts, etc.)  (Hope that makes sense) (Unfortunately, due to CORS I cannot edit the remote URL source.

Comment: Ok, now I see what and why you're trying to achieve. You say that you're attempting to insert the `base` tag, can you show how have you attempted that?

Comment: <?php  
echo '<base href="https://www.theurl.com/">';  
$url = 'https://www.theurl.com/buyflow/buyflow-localization.html';  
$probe = file_get_contents($url);  
echo $probe; 
  ?>
This code works to load everything, so mission accomplished. However, how does one actually insert code within the iframe DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `base` should be inside the `head` element. A possible solution would be to use the `DOMDocument` class to manipulate the document. Something like this:

```
$dirUrl = 'https://theurl.com/buyflow/';
$url = $dirUrl . 'buyflow-localization.html';
$probe = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($probe);

$head = $doc->getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; // try also ->item(0) instead of [0]
$bases = $head->getElementsByTagName('base');
if(count($bases) == 0) {
    $base = $doc->createElement('base');
    $head->appendChild($base);
} else
    $base = $bases[0]; // same here
$base->setAttribute('href', $dirUrl);

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Wow, exactly what I was trying to do! Thanks so much!

Comment: @Rain by the way, did this work for you exacly like this? Looks like `[0]` should actually be `->item(0)`

Comment: no it didn't work perfectly, but it DID help me identify that the <base> tag already exists. Now I just gotta figure out how to replace it :)

Comment: both before & after replacing [0] with ->item(0) i get the following: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mo\proxy.php:14

Comment: @Rain as of the error, try to substitute `DOMDocument::createElement('base');` with `$doc->createElement('base');`. As for your case, you set an `else` action. I'll modify the code, but keep in mind I haven't tested that yet.

Comment: the first part of the code throws Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity, line: 518 in C:\xampp\htdocs\mo\proxy.php on line 7 (Line7: $doc->loadHTML($probe);) Then we throw about 10 more errors as the extremely bloated page loads . In addition, no content is loaded.

Comment: @Rain sounds like they have broken markup in their page.. Have you tried to echo `$probe` and to check the line 518? Probably this deserves a separate question since there's a number of details to be posted in a formatted way. Or at least edit this one – like "I've tried ... and got ..."